# Determine probability of an event $A$ with a PMF

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Suppose the sequence $(\frac{1 - q}{1 + q}q^{|n|})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ with $|q| < 1$ is a probability mass function.

*Proof that it is a valid probability mass function:*

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1 - q}{1 + q}q^{|n|} = \frac{1 - q}{1 + q}\big(1 + 2\frac{q}{1 - q}\big) = 1$$

Now, how can I determine the probability of the event $A = \{2k; k \in \mathbb{N} \} = \{2,4,6,...\}$?

Would this be determined with $\frac{1 - q}{1 + q}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{2|n|}$ ?

Comment: Yes.  That is the correct way to calculate the probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the probability

$$\frac{1 - q}{1 + q}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{2|n|} = \frac{(1 - q)(1 + q^2)}{(1 + q)(1-q^2)} = \frac{(1 + q^2)}{(1 + q)^2}$$

is the probability of the event $B = \{2k| k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

The probability of the event $A = \{2k| k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is computed as

$$\frac{1 - q}{1 + q}\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{2|n|} = \frac{(1 - q)q^2}{(1 + q)(1 - q^2)} = \frac{q^2}{(1 + q)^2}$$